Sakashima of a Thousand Faces and its "other abilities"
Sakashima of a Thousand Faces specifies "other abilities" and I'm a bit confused as to what "other" refers to exactly.
Let's say I have a Rhythm of the Wild in play. I then play my Sakashima as itself, choosing to give it haste due to the riot ability. Sakashima now has its own abilities as well as haste and riot. I then play a Clone choosing to have it enter as my Sakashima. Since Sakashima also has an "enter as" effect, it's my understanding that I can then also apply that effect, having it enter again as Sakashima. Will the Clone then also have haste and riot from Sakashima + another instance of riot from Rhythm of the Wild, or does "other abilities" simply refer to the abilities printed on the card?

Sakashima has three abilities: the copy ability, the legend rule ability, and partner. When the copy ability refers to its "other abilities", it means the legend rule ability and partner.
Haste and riot from Rhythm of the Wilds would not be copied because the effect that grants those abilities is not a copyable effect. Rule 702.2 covers what characteristics and effects are copyable:

When copying an object, the copy acquires the copiable values of the original object's characteristics and, for an object on the stack, choices made when casting or activating it (mode, targets, the value of X, whether it was kicked, how it will affect multiple targets, and so on). The copiable values are the values derived from the text printed on the object (that text being name, mana cost, color indicator, card type, subtype, supertype, rules text, power, toughness, and/or loyalty), as modified by other copy effects, by its face-down status, and by "as . . . enters" and "as . . . is turned face up" abilities that set power and toughness (and may also set additional characteristics). Other effects (including type-changing and text-changing effects), status, counters, and stickers are not copied.

As a result, if you control a Sakashima of a Thousand Faces with riot and haste from Rhythm of the Wilds, and you play a Clone, first Clone's replacement effect applies, and it becomes a copy of Sakashima as printed. Then Sakashima's replacement effect applies, and it becomes a copy of Sakashima as printed, as modified by the copy effect. This means that it has an additional instance of the legend rule ability and partner. Then riot's replacement effect applies, and it enters with either haste or a +1/+1 counter.

This gets more interesting if you consider abilities granted by other copy effects, because those are copyable. For example, if you have a Dack's Duplicate copy of Sakashima, its copy effect grants it haste and dethrone. If it applies its instance of Sakashima's replacement effect, I believe the "other abilities" in that case would also refer to haste and dethrone, and it would gain those too. I can't find any relevant rules or rulings about this though, because Sakashima is the only card that refers to "other abilities" in that way.

Thanks for the answer! Just a follow-up question, in rule 702.2 which you references, the text "and by "as . . . enters" and "as . . . is turned face up" abilities that set power and toughness (and may also set additional characteristics)." sounds to me as if it would include the haste given by riot, why isn't this the case?

Riot doesn't set power and toughness.

Wouldn't hase be included in "and may also set additional characteristics"?

That is "additional" as in "in addition to setting power and toughness".

Ah, I see. Thanks!
